# How to ignore property using graphdiff?

Tags: properties, edmx, graphdiff

I'm using EF6 with graphdiff and EDMX and must ignore a property of a particular entity.

How should I do since even getting the property the insert or update always leave the NULL field?

Comment: Did you find anything out on this?

Comment: Unfortunately have not found any solution to this I circled my problem otherwise.

Answer (score 5):

The way I was able to work around this while still benefiting from the ease of GraphDiff was as follows:

- Set your object equal to the GraphDiff method
- Set each property you wish to ignore to .IsModified = false

(Example)

```
  user = db.UpdateGraph(user, map => map
            .AssociatedCollection(u => u.UserRoles)
            .AssociatedCollection(u => u.Teams));

    db.Entry(user).Property(u => u.Password).IsModified = false;
    db.Entry(user).Property(u => u.Salt).IsModified = false;

    _context.SaveChanges();
```